# Group by and aggregation on Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, aggregate

I have a table which has the following format (Google Big query) :

| user | url | val1 | val2 | val3 | ... | val300 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | a | 0.5 | 0 | -3 | ... | 1 |
| A | b | 1 | 2 | 3 | ... | 2 |
| B | c | 5 | 4 | -10 | ... | 2 |

I would like to obtain a new table where I obtain the number of urls by user, and vals are aggregated by average. (The number of different vals can be variable so I would like to have something rather flexible)

| user | nb_url | val1 | val2 | val3 | ... | val300 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 0.75 | 1 | 0 | ... | 1.5 |
| B | 1 | ... |  |  |  |  |

What is the good syntax?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Search for "dynamic pivot bigquery"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate by user, select the count of URLs, and the average of the other columns.

```sql
SELECT
    user,
    COUNT(*) AS nb_url,
    AVG(val1) AS val1,
    AVG(val2) AS val2,
    AVG(val3) AS val3,
    ...
    AVG(val300) AS val300
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY user
ORDER BY user;
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to avoid writing avg(val1),avg(val2) etc. ?

Comment: No, but you might be able to write code which generates the `AVG` expressions for you.

Answer (score 0):

Generating pivot for 300 columns can be quite expensive even for BigQuery - instead I would recommend below [unpivoted] solution

```
select user, count(url) nb_url, 
  offset + 1 col, avg(cast(val as float64)) as val
from your_table t,
unnest(split(translate(format('%t', (select as struct * except(user, url) from unnest([t]))), '() ', ''))) val with offset
group by user, col
```

if applied to sample data as in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I have to keep my tables in pivot format, I have to use these columns to do Machine Learning techniques