# Generate column list with select statement for unpivot

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, unpivot

I have a very wide table that I'm trying to unpivot without literally listing the hundreds of columns.

I thought something like this should work

```
WITH column_names_table as (
  SELECT column_name
  FROM `my_project.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
  WHERE 
    table_name = 'my_table'
    AND NOT column_name = 'time_utc'
)

SELECT time_utc, measurement, identifier 
FROM `my_project.dataset.my_table`
    UNPIVOT(
        measurement FOR identifier IN 
        (SELECT column_name from column_names_table)
    )
```

but I get a `Syntax error: Unexpected keyword SELECT`. If i just replace the SELECT statement with a literal list of the columns this works. I seems like i'm so close here...

Can I make this work?
If not, is there another way to unpivot all columns except a couple?
I'm also wondering if there's a good reason this isn't possible..

Input data:

| time_utc | id1 | id2 | ... | idN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-24 05:00:00 UTC | 0.5 | 1.2 |  | 12 |
| 2019-01-24 06:00:00 UTC | 0.6 | 1.3 |  | 1.2 |

Output data:

| time_utc | measurement | identifier |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-24 05:00:00 UTC | 0.5 | id1 |
| 2019-01-24 06:00:00 UTC | 0.6 | id1 |
| 2019-01-24 05:00:00 UTC | 1.2 | id2 |
| 2019-01-24 06:00:00 UTC | 1.3 | id2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Comment: Can you provide a sample and expected data? Especially for the values of `my_table`. Just so the community members can properly reproduce the issue.

Comment: I added sample data, but should point out one doesn't need to use plug this in necessarily. I think the error / ask is reproducible with basically any table with more than one column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't specify columns to unpivot dynamically, you need to consider a dynamic sql if you use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view.

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  SELECT time_utc, measurement, identifier 
    FROM `my_project.dataset.my_table` 
 UNPIVOT (measurement FOR identifier IN (%s))
""", (
  SELECT STRING_AGG(column_name) 
    FROM `my_project.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
   WHERE table_name = 'my_table' AND NOT column_name = 'time_utc'
));
```

###### Query results

[image]

And you might consider  @Mikhail's another approach in below link if
INFORMATION_SCHEMA or a dynamic sql is not available to you.

- [Group by and aggregation on Bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74291620/group-by-and-aggregation-on-bigquery/74298360#74298360)

below query is a slightly modified one to suit your case having same output above.

```sql
select time_utc, measurement, 'id' || (offset + 1) identifier
from `dataset.my_table` t,
unnest(split(translate(format('%t', (select as struct * except(time_utc) from unnest([t]))), '() ', ''))) measurement with offset;
```

###### Sample Dataset

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS dataset;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dataset.my_table AS 
SELECT '2019-01-24 05:00:00 UTC' time_utc, 0.5 id1, 1.2 id2, 1.0 id3, 1.2 id4 UNION ALL
SELECT '2019-01-24 06:00:00 UTC', 0.6, 1.3, 1.2, 1.4;
```

Comment: Thanks! Any chance you can explain why SELECT isn't allowed after the 'IN'. Doesn't this kind of thing work in WHERE clauses?

Comment: Obviously, you can use select subquery along with **IN** operator in WHERE clauses which is a short form of multiple OR conditions. see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#in_operators . but here **FOR.. IN**  with unpivot, only a form of tuple is allowed at the moment.  see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unpivot_operator